# Add model parameters and Run timestamp to scored results

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have run an Azure machine learning experiment in Studio and currently am exporting the scored results to Azure SQL.
I want to include in the export data, the "run timestamp" and the model configuration as extra columns.
This is usefull because i can then compare the results from different runs against each other in my Azure SQL database.

Anyone know how to add this data to the scored data set ?

Thanks in advance,

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Apply SQL Transformation module to generate the timestamp for each row of scored data, as well as a new string column containing the model configuration.
If you are more comfortable with R, you could use the Execute R Script module to create the new columns.

Comment: Interesting. This works when I manually provide the values for the model type (such as the regression type used)
Any idea how to automatically input the model configuration (such as the regression type used) into the column ? ;-)